# How to add two arguments to a UIButton target's action?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I know this question has been asked before, however, I am trying to pass two arrays of UITextFields to the action method.

```
    calculate.addTarget(self, action: Selector("calculate::"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

The function is declared as follows:

```
    func calculate(textFieldsTheory : [UITextField], textFieldPractical : [UITextField])
```

I get the warning "No method declared with Objective-C selector calculate:: "

Comment: Did you review those other questions? Did you look at their solutions? You can't pass any custom parameters to the button's selector.

Comment: Yes I did. And yes I've come to that conclusion! I used a class variable instead of passing anything to the action

Answer (score -1):

You can create NSDictionary of those array and pass it as single argument.